# jquery select element by attribute in IE8 and IE9

Tags: jquery, select, attributes

```
window.jQuery.('body').on('click','td[clickurl],tr[clickurl],li[clickurl]',
  function(ev){
    location.href = window.jQuery.(this).attr('clickurl');
});
```

using jquery 1.9.1, not working in IE < 10

Comment: It shouldn't be working in any browser at all. `window.jQuery.('body')` isn't valid JavaScript. Neither is `jQuery.(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is wrong.

```
window.jQuery.('body')
```

Instead of it, just write

```
$('body')
```

Also you can access all elements with `clickurl` attribute with `[clickurl]` selector:

```
$('body').on('click', '[clickurl]', function() {
    location.href = $(this).attr('clickurl');
});
```

---

#### NOTE

`$` is an alias name for `jQuery`, if you want, you can use `jQuery` too:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '[clickurl]', function() {
    location.href = jQuery(this).attr('clickurl');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is syntactically incorrect. It should fail in all browsers with a syntax exception. it should be

```
jQuery('body').on('click','td[clickurl],tr[clickurl],li[clickurl]',function(ev){
    location.href = jQuery(this).attr('clickurl');
});
```